# rpm -e package does not remove entry from /etc/passwd

Tags: centos, rpm

I've been playing around with Splunk and got some questions:

1. I have installed it using

   > rpm -iv splunk-7.2.3-06d57c595b80-linux-2.6-x86_64.rpm
2. I removed it next using

> rpm -e splunk-7.2.3-06d57c595b80.x86_64

My question is, why didn't `rpm` remove the Splunk user from /etc/passwd ? Also I'm a bit puzzled why removing via `splunk-7.2.3-06d57c595b80-linux-2.6-x86_64.rpm` did not work (but the installation did) and I had to get the actual package name with `rpm -qa | grep splunk` first?

Is this related to the `Splunk` `rpm` package or rather standard?

Comment: It's a general policy issue (and likely a duplicate).  Removing a user requires one to ensure that there are no leftover files belonging to the deleted user.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thank you. What do you mean "general policy issue"?

Comment: Leaving files owned by an unspecified user (only a number) is considered by some a security problem.  Reducing problems like that is a *policy*. See [this](https://ma.ttias.be/on-removing-users-with-postun-in-rpm-spec-files/)

Comment: To add to the second part of your question, you don't include the `.rpm` part of the package when removing it via `rpm -e`.

Answer (score 0):

rpm packages consist of a bunch of files and optionally a group of scripts (pre/postinstall pre/postremove pre/postupgrade verify)

You can use the --list option to show what files are part of the package.  These will be removed when you --erase the package.

```
rpm -qipl package.rpm
```

You can also include --scripts to dump the contents of the scripts.  There isn't a whole lot of standardized templates or enforcement on how install / remove scripts work, so it's really up to the package maintainer.  But you can certainly dump the --scripts of a package to discover exactly what an RPM is doing to your system so you can better write your own cleanup scripts.

```
rpm -qi --scripts package.rpm
```

You might even consider installing with --noscripts if you just need some files from an rpm and don't want or don't trust the maintainer to dink with the configuration of your system.

Answer (score 0):

Not removing a user together with a package is a standard.

Thomas already provided nice explanation in comments and linked this nice document https://ma.ttias.be/on-removing-users-with-postun-in-rpm-spec-files/

However, there is another reason. Many admins rely on LDAP or NIS to provide users to the system. And even before installing package which creates new user, they will first add that user to their LDAP. This is the reason why new users are created using:

```
getent passwd USERNAME >/dev/null || \
    useradd -r -g GROUPNAME -d HOMEDIR -s /sbin/nologin ...
```

i.e. before the user is created, the package should always check if the user already has been created.

And of course, you simply cannot remove LDAP user from a client system. So simple `userdel` may likely fail. So it is up to the admin to remove the user - using the tools he uses for user management.